# Fear of death is prior feature of human T or F

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, death, immortality

A group of people have the fear of death, another group of people do not, the group of people that do not have fear of death believe the consequence is to go to heaven. Part of the first group think of they die, they lose all they have, which is having the fear of death is because the result or consequence, the other part of the first group state there is no reason to fear death, having a fear of death is the natural human feature.

Do the fear of death come naturally when people born, or it has been considered deeply by the people with the fear of its consequence.

Comment: I stand with the second proposition in the last paragraph

Comment: "philosophy of mind" ???